# SQLITE3 GROUP BY "anniversary date"

Tags: sqlite

I have data stored in a SQLITE3 database with this format:

```
id | ts | data ...
475158|2019-11-12 07:50:00 | ...
```

So I used to group by day, month, year, eg:

```sql
SELECT STRFTIME("%Y-%m", ts), SUM(<data in my table>)
FROM ( <my table> )
GROUP BY STRFTIME("%Y-%m", ts)
ORDER BY ts
```

Now I would like to do the same but based on an anniversary date.

For example if the anniversary date is 2010-11-17, I would like to get a result grouped by year but between 'YYYY'-11-17 and 'YYYY+1'-11-16

Example:

```
2017 |sum of data between  2016-11-17 & 2017-11-16
2018 |sum of data between  2017-11-17 & 2018-11-16
2019 |sum of data between  2018-11-17 & 2019-11-16
```

Is it possible easily?

Comment: Try this:
 SELECT STRFTIME("%Y-%m", ts) as avYear, SUM(<data in my table>)
FROM ( <my table> )
GROUP BY avYear
ORDER BY ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the *year* in your case by this expression:

```
strftime('%Y', ts) + (substr(ts, 6, 5) >= '11-17')
```

so do this:

```
select 
  strftime('%Y', ts) + (substr(ts, 6, 5) >= '11-17') year,
  sum(data) total
from tablename  
group by year
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4sjRkmVQ7BVpX6acRBUvJ1/1).

Comment: Impressive! Many thanks @forpas. You play on the fact that boolean are well defined integers (0 false & 1 true). As soon as the date is greater than anniversary month & day, the year is automatically incremented. You did it, very well! Thx again!